# Throttle limits for MWS Orders API

Tags: amazon-mws

In the [documentation](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/mwsportal/doc/en_US/orders/2013-09-01/MWSOrdersApiReference._V322383903_.pdf) it states:

`The ListOrders and ListOrdersByNextToken operations together share a maximum request quota of 6 and a restore rate of 60.`

It was my understanding that this means I could do something like this:

- Call `ListOrders`: request quota  = 5, orders downloaded = 100
- Call `ListOrdersByNextToken`: request quota  = 4, orders downloaded = 200
- Call `ListOrdersByNextToken`: request quota  = 3, orders downloaded = 300
- Call `ListOrdersByNextToken`: request quota  = 2, orders downloaded = 400
- Call `ListOrdersByNextToken`: request quota  = 1, orders downloaded = 500
- Call `ListOrdersByNextToken`: request quota  = 0, orders downloaded = 600

Then, since the restore rate is 60, after 6 minutes my request quota would be back to 6 and I could repeat the process. If I submit all the requests back-to-back, I could pull 600 orders every 6 minutes per merchant.

**QUESTIONS:**

1. Is my understanding of the throttle limit correct?
2. If it is correct, why have I been able to pull over 1000 orders in less than a minute? The only reason the program stops is that the merchant has no more orders to be pulled.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In my testing in February 2017, requests for `ListOrdersByNextToken` do, in fact, count against your request quota for `ListOrders`.

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that the `...NextToken` calls do not count towards the throttling limits. That means you've only made *one* call as far as throttling is concerned.

Comment: Is there anywhere in the documentation that specifically mentions that? I guess I was confused when it said `The ListOrders and ListOrdersByNextToken operations **together** share a maximum request quota of 6 and a restore rate of 60`

Comment: @pez Not that I recall. I believe my assumption came from the processing cost involved. `ListOrders` is an expensive call which will build en entire temporary table while the ...NextToken calls are cheap since they only pull data from said table. It makes sense to limit (throttle) one but not the other.

Comment: In my testing in February 2017, requests for `ListOrdersByNextToken` do count against your request quota.

Comment: @jbryanscott Plese change that comment to an answer. It seems this may have changed recently - and if it did, my previous answer is now wrong. A comment is harder to find for anybody with the same problem later on.